# How to use only tools of Adobe Creative SDK in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, adobecreativesdk

I trying to create photo editing app. I searched on internet and i found Adobe Creative SDK is good for editing an image and I gone through there documentations found good.But here the thing is I want to use only there tools instead of redirecting me to `AdobeUXImageEditorViewController` I want to use only the tools(frames,Stickers,Brush etc). So is it possible to do that or we have to that controller?

If Yes can somebody please help me with any sample code.

Below is the code of redirecting my uiimage to AdobeUXImageEditorViewController controller

```js
- (void)launchPhotoEditorWithImage:(UIImage*)image
{
    // Create photo editor
    AdobeUXImageEditorViewController *editorController = [[AdobeUXImageEditorViewController alloc] initWithImage:image];
    [editorController setDelegate:self];
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:editorController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)photoEditor:(AdobeUXImageEditorViewController *)editor finishedWithImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    UIImage *imageToEdit=image;
    _imageViewForEditing.image=imageToEdit;
    // Handle the result image here and dismiss the editor.
    //[self doSomethingWithImage:image]; // Developer-defined method that presents the final editing-resolution image to the user, perhaps.
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)photoEditorCanceled:(AdobeUXImageEditorViewController *)editor
{
    // Dismiss the editor.
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use of the ViewController is required. There is no way to access the tools without the ViewController.